# Xubuntu: Error while installing xfce-theme-manager 15.10

Tags: xubuntu, themes, 15.10, xfce

Could somebody please tell me how to install xfce-theme-manager from the Rubuntu16 repository because when I try to install this, it just does not meet all the package dependencies and frankly I've had no problem installing this before until now.

Here's my computer's specifications:

- CPU: Intel Celeron 1005M 1.90GHz
- RAM: DDR3 4GB 1600 MHz
- Graphics: IvyBridge Mobile/Intel HD

Thanks.

Comment: What is Rubuntu16, which repository do you mean, which dependency problems do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Okay with some troubleshooting I have found how to do this however this could be dangerous.

To install `xfce-theme-manager` on xubuntu 15.10 or later it requires editing sources.

---

Open a terminal and type:

```
su
apt-add-repository ppa:rebuntu16/other-stuff
apt-get update    
apt-get install gksu //This allows shell applications to be ran as root    
gksudo thunar
```

---

In the file manager that was opened from the command, go to `/ect/apt/sources.list.d/` and edit the rebuntu16 source and change both sources from "wily main" to "vivid main"

---

Back to the terminal, type:

```
su
apt-get update
apt-get install xfce-theme-manager
```